# Add stage variable in aws api gateway via cli

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

What is the right syntax for doing this via the aws cli?

```
aws apigateway update-stage --rest-api-id $api_id --stage-name 'test_stage' --patch-operations op="add",path=/variables,value="{server:8.8.8.8}"
```

I can't get the last part `value=".."` right. The documentation isn't very helpful to me.

Answer (score 8):

I got it working after numerous trial and error:

> aws apigateway update-stage --rest-api-id $api_id --stage-name
>   'test_stage' --patch-operations
>   op="replace",path=/variables/server,value="8.8.8.8"

op="replace" works instead of "add" (odd for me as i am trying to add a variable). The variable name is in the path and the value after that. AWS return me the following response after executing the command this way:

```
{
    "stageName": "test_stage", 
    "variables": {
        "server": "8.8.8.8"
    }, 
    "cacheClusterEnabled": false, 
    "cacheClusterStatus": "NOT_AVAILABLE", 
    "deploymentId": "kg39574", 
    "lastUpdatedDate": 1512838534, 
    "createdDate": 1512705498, 
    "methodSettings": {}
}
```

Comment: For future reference this is document in our API reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/stage-update/

Comment: It complained for me when I added the single quotes around the stage-name.  You may need to remove it.

Comment: how can we add multiple values at a single stretch? I have a hell a lot of stage variables and finding it hard when I want to re-create them, is there an option to copy from another API Gateway?.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try

Replace the double quotes with single quotes

```
aws apigateway update-stage \
--rest-api-id $api_id \
--stage-name 'test_stage' \
--patch-operations op='add',path=/variables,value='{server:8.8.8.8}'
```

Escape the `{}` characters

```
aws apigateway update-stage \
--rest-api-id $api_id \
--stage-name 'test_stage' \
--patch-operations op="add",path=/variables,value="\{server:8.8.8.8\}"
```

[Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-using-param.html) for parameters in cli